# Redmine Add multiple watchers through rest api

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I need to create Redmine issues through api. I have an xml draft, that is posted to the redmine by wget.exe. The xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<issue>
  <project_id>145</project_id>
  <tracker_id>10</tracker_id>
  <category_id>885</category_id>
  <subject>subj</subject>
  <description>descript</description>
  <watcher_user_ids>1333,1614</watcher_user_ids>
</issue>
```

It works almost fine except adding watchers to the issue. According to documentation parameter `<watcher_user_ids>` contains array of watchers. But I can't make it work for multiple watchers. Somehow it adds only the first one and others are ignored. I've tried to use ";", "," separators, different brackets, but it doesn't help. I guess I'm doing something wrong. Can please anybody help me and show me the right way.

Answer (score 2):

I could not make this work at all with Redmine version 2.5.2.stable.  The only thing that worked for me is:

POST /issues/[id]/watchers.[format]

where watchers.json is:

{"user_id": "11"}

It makes sense since the watchers table references the issue and the issue contains no reference to watchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<watcher_user_ids>1333</watcher_user_ids>
<watcher_user_ids>1614</watcher_user_ids>
```

Comment: Your answer contains only code. Can you ad some explanation?

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve I changed XML to JSON format and everything worked perfectly:

```
{
  "issue": {
    "project_id": 145,
    "category_id": 885
    "subject": "subj",
    "description": "descript",
    "watcher_user_ids": ["133","1614"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a line for each watcher you want to add.

```
<watcher_user_ids>1333</watcher_user_ids>
<watcher_user_ids>1614</watcher_user_ids>
```

In this example 2 watchers will be added.